# Oracle Update multiple columns with same value

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

Lets suppose I created one table--

```
Create table t1 (aa varchar2(5),bb varchar2(5),cc varchar2(5));
```

Inserted values in it--

```
insert into T1 values ('a','b','c');
commit;
```

Now in one scenario,  if i wanted to update all columns with same value then I am doing by this way--

```
UPDATE T1 SET AA='x',BB='x',CC='x';
```

Is there any another way by which this update task can be accomplished considering in real time there may be quite large number of columns and all has to be updated with same value in one go?

> I am using Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

**Note**: Usually there are very less any scenarios where same values are being updated for all columns. But for example consider a school database and  a good student scores 10/10 marks in all subjects. :-)

Thanks.

Comment: No, and why should there? You only build the query once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do it in pure **SQL**. You must list down all the **columns** explicitly in the UPDATE statement.

And, believe me it is not a difficult task using a good **text editor**. Using the metadata you could get the list of column names in few seconds, all you need to do is prepare the SQL statement as per the syntax.

If you really want to do it *dynamically*, then you need to do it in **PL/SQL** and (ab)use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. I would personally not suggest it unless you are just doing it for learning purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
UPDATE T1 SET AA='x',BB=AA,CC=AA;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.